# htaccess subsubdomain rewrite without redirect

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I'm not even sure where to start here. I've made a php script which grabs the user ID from the URL and displays some basic user info. But, I want the user to go to a sub-sub-domain and still be able to grab the ID as normal.

So, if a user goes to username.my.domain.com, I want to be able to grab the username from a script located in domain.com/users/display.php

Without the subdomain part it's something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^my/(.*)$ users/display.php?user=$1[L]
```

But I can't make enough sense of my google results to figure out the subdomain part.

Could anyone help me out with this?

..........................................................................

EDIT:

OK, I only have 3 files on my server:

```
domain.com/.htaccess
domain.com/index.html
domain.com/users/display.php
```

When I visit http://domain.com/users/display.php?user=joe the page displays "joe"

Using this code as my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.my\.(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%1/users/display.php?user=%1 [L,QSA,R]
```

In domain.com/users I get this error log:

[05-Feb-2014 02:26:46 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/suhosin.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

[05-Feb-2014 02:26:46 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/newrelic.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/newrelic.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: So you want to grab ``foobar` from `foobar.my.domain.com` and then want to load `/users/display.php?user=foobar`?

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Have another rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.my\.(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%1/users/display.php?user=%1 [L,QSA,R]
```

Comment: That isn't working for me. It just throws me to a "website unavailable" page

Comment: No, if I go to domain.com/users/display.php?user=hello, that works. if I go to my.domain.com I get a 404 Not Found, but when I go to hello.my.domain.com it spits me to "website unavailable"

Comment: This rule targets only `hello.my.domain.com` as per your requirement and I have made another update.

Comment: I guess your requirements still aren't clear. How do want to handle `my.domain.com` URLs? What are some example URLs you want to handle and what are their expected outcomes?

Comment: my.domain.com will have an index.php and shouldn't be affected. I need joe.my.domain.com to show domain.com/users/display.php?user=joe. I tweeted you!

Comment: That doesn't work, "website unavailable". It also makes every other page give me an Internal Server Error. I'm totally lost in these examples now.

Comment: Post your complete .htaccess and check your Apache error.log to see what the actual error is.

Comment: Ok, I was getting Internal Server Error with "Options -Indexes", but still no joy with the sub-sub-domain. Still "website unavailable". I've added the error log to the original question.